# SafariViewControllerDidFinish does not fire when swiping down to dismiss

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller, sfsafariviewcontrollerdelegate

I have a delegate on a `SFSafariViewController` that does clean up tasks in the `safariViewControllerDidFinish` event. In iOS 13+, the user is able to swipe down to dismiss, but this event is not fired in that case. I do not want to disable this gesture by enabling `isModalInPresentation`.

Is there a way to make the `safariViewControllerDidFinish` fire for this case, or how can I detect the user swiping down to dismiss the Safari view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can know when the user dismisses the `SFSafariViewController` by swiping down by making yourself the presentation controller's delegate and overriding `presentationControllerDidDismiss(_:)`. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiadaptivepresentationcontrollerdelegate/3229889-presentationcontrollerdiddismiss) on this topic.

Note: This method will not get called if you use `dismiss(animated:)` programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

@Frankenstein's answer worked for me, but it took me a while to setup my code correctly, so just want to add some code snippets here

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

  func presentSafariVC() {
    let url = //...
    let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
    safariVC.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    safariVC.delegate = self
    safariVC.presentationController?.delegate = self
    present(safariVC, animated: true)
  }

}
```

```swift
extension MyViewController: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {

  // click top left "Done" button and dismissed
  func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
        // do your stuff
  }
    
  // swipe down and dismissed
  func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
        // do your stuff
  }

}
```

Also, I was originally looking for a way to prevent swipe down to dismiss the presented vc, but it seems setting `safariVC.isModalInPresentation = true` has no effect, I can still swipe down to dismiss it. This is observed on XCode 12, iOS 14.2 simulator.

Comment: Same issue as you. This should be the accepted answer. Thanks!